# How to crop an image in the preview right after the picture is taken?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am having a headache of croping users' photos after they have picked up an image as profile pic. Do anyone has ideas how I can make it, just like what Facebook does, that the image is dimmed except a pre-determined square which users can move it to crop/select which part they want.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

allowsEditing = YES should help getting this to show.